# Question about filling a 2D array in Python

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

What I want is to fill a 3*3 array. This code works as intended:

```
arr = [ [] ] * 3
for i in range(3): 
    arr[i] = (list(map(int, input().split()[:3])))
print(arr)
```

But if I write it like this:

```
arr = [ [] ] * 3
for i in arr: 
    arr[i] = (list(map(int, input().split()[:3])))
print(arr)
```

It gives an error: "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list".

What am I doing wrong in second example?

Comment: Try insert `print(i)`  in for loop to understand what values `i` take in each case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to run this snippet:

```
arr = [ [] ] * 3
for i in arr: 
    print(i)
```

the result should be like this:

```
[]
[]
[]
```

When you try to assign the result to `arr[i]`, actually you assign to `arr[[]]` which raises the error `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list`. Your array element should be accessed with integer or slices. For example `arr[1]` or `arr[0:3]`.

The solution to your code is:

```
arr = [ [] ] * 3
for i in len(range(3)): 
    arr[i] = (list(map(int, input().split()[:3])))
print(arr)
```